# Infinite series: existence of power to ensure finiteness

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq[0,1]$ be a sequence converging to $0$. Does there always exist a real number $r\in[0,\infty)$ such that $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|a_n|^r<\infty$? Does such real number exist, for example, for the series $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|\frac{1}{log(n+1)}|^r$?

Comment: @Hurkyl, $r=1$?

Comment: Well it is bedtime but I will try to answer the last part of your questior. For your last series, then the sum $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{log(n+1)^2}$$ and then integral $$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac {1}{log(x+1)^r}dx$$
Will diverge or converge precisely in the same time. For the integral, it might be easier to see that such $r$ does not exist. Otherwise, try the comparison test, d'Alemberts criteria or the root test, at least one of them should work out pretty easy.